# Solving a tridiagonal matrix in matlab using Thomas algorithm

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, matlab

Hello I have this tridiagonal matrix.
[image]

where $$r =  \frac1x , g=  \frac{1}{ x^2 } , s= \frac{\ln x}{ x^2 }  $$ and n represents the size.
I'm trying to solve this matrix in Matlab using the Thomas algorithm. I have found some online resources however they dont tend to deal with when n becomes very large.
Sorry for this vague description, I'm quite new to using matlab.

Comment: Just use sparse matrices and backslash operator in Matlab. No need to implement something yourselves.

Comment: There is no clear question here. What is the actual problem? Implementing the algorithm using limited storage or making sense of the results? You need to be specific.